# In VB.net, how can two read-only properties with no parameters overload eachother?

Tags: vb.net, properties, overloading, readonly

I've noticed that a class can "overload" a read-only property of its parent class, even though this isn't allowed within a class.  I don't understand why this is allowed or what (if anything) it accomplishes.

```
Class myClass
    ReadOnly Property SomeProp As Integer
        Get
            Return 50
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Class mySubClass
    Inherits myClass    
    Overloads ReadOnly Property SomeProp As Integer
        Get
            Return 12
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The signature of `mySubClass.SomeProp` is identical to `myClass.Prop`—how can the former overload the latter?

In practice this seems to function just like `Shadows`, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence yes, with the overload you'll have myClass::SomeProp and mySubClass::SomeProp

Given an instance of mySubClass, calls to SomeProp will resolve to mySubClass::SomeProp as the best match.  However since it's Overloads and not Shadows, something like

```
Readonly Property SomeProp(x as Integer) as integer)
  Get
    Return 13
  End Get
End Property
```

won't compile since it lacks the Overloads decorator.